# how to handle online images in Parse

Tags: ios

so I'm using Parse in my app as backend cloud service. I looked into Parse documents and see that they have PFFile method which can upload local images to Parse, and PFImageView class to retrieve remote image from Parse. But in my app, we have a lot of online images with URLs, and how can I easily display these images in my app without worrying about caches and all? Or is there any way to download and upload online images to Parse easily so that I can just use Parse's service?

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't loading images from Parse, there's no reason to use PFFile or PFImageView. Downloading and uploading them would be redundant if you know they will remain available at their respective URL's. This will allow you to load images asynchronously (in the background) from a URL:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://myurl/mypic.jpg"]];
        if ( data == nil )
            return;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImageView *imView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData: data]];
        });
    });
```

As far as cacheing goes, if your images are large you may notice a delay in their loading and may still need to cache. This is one of the most popular solutions:

https://github.com/path/FastImageCache

Comment: Actually, I want to load images from Parse, because Parse's PFImageView can handle caches and load in background for me , and it's really simple. So I need to figure out a way to save those URL images to Parse. Not just URLs , but actual image files.

Comment: How many URLs? If it's few then you can upload images manually and if it's many you could write a cloud code function to download and save them.

Comment: around 3500 and counting, do you have a sample code to download and save them?